# Entanglement entropy and reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

I'm learning about the definition of von Neumann entanglement entropy

$$S(\rho_1)=-\text{Tr}[\rho_1\ln\rho_1]$$
where $\rho_1$ is the reduced density matrix $\rho_1=\text{Tr}_2(\rho)$.

I was confused that the entanglement entropy of a bipartite pure state is different if it is defined using the von Neumann entropy of the reduced density matrix of subsystem 2? i.e., is the following equation correct?
$$S(\rho_1)=-\text{Tr}[\rho_1\ln\rho_1]=S(\rho_2)=-\text{Tr}[\rho_2\ln\rho_2]$$
If it's true, how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: Make sure to understand that (and how) the von Neumann entropy only depends on the spectrum of the corresponding density matrix. Then, for a *pure* state, you can use results of the Schmidt decomposition (both reduced density matrices have the same non-zero eigenvalues) to show that the last equality holds true.

Comment: Just to be very clear here: The equality in general is false for mixed states $\rho$ and one can construct easy counter examples!

Answer (score 1):

Using Schmidt decomposition, we can generally write a bipartite pure state as
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_i a_i |\varphi_i\rangle\otimes|\phi_i\rangle$$
and the density matrix of the total system is
$$\rho=\sum_{ij}a_ia^*_j|\varphi_i\rangle\otimes|\phi_i\rangle\langle\varphi_j|\otimes\langle\phi_j|$$
thus the reduced density matrices are
$$\rho_1=\text{Tr}_2(\rho)=\sum_i|a_i|^2|\varphi_i\rangle\langle\varphi_i|$$
$$\rho_2=\text{Tr}_1(\rho)=\sum_i|a_i|^2|\phi_i\rangle\langle\phi_i|$$
since $\langle\varphi_i|\varphi_j\rangle=\langle\phi_i|\phi_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Thus the entanglement entropy is
$$S(\rho_1)=S(\rho_2)=-\sum_i|a_i|^2\ln|a_i|^2$$